# Filtering rows and counting columns - can Reduce or Filter do that?

Tags: r

I have a table like so:

```
1   2   3   4   5
a   b   a       c
b   b           
a   a       a   a
c   b       c   b
```

Is there a special syntax to use for either Filter or Reduce (or something else entirely?) to get it so only the rows with an 'a' (including blanks) are shown? Likewise, is there a built-in way to count the frequency of 'a' for each column or would I have to loop over those individually?

Comment: Is this a data.frame? A matrix? A table? It would be more helpful to see the `dput()` of the object.

Comment: colSums( X == "a") for the second part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of a way to pass rows or columns to Reduce or Filter to achieve the first, although a data.frame might get passed in a column-wise fashion for the second question since it is a list of columns. `apply` is the usual mechanism for doing row-wise operations, but I can think of quicker methods. For the first, under the assumption it is named `X` and is either a matrix or a data.frame:

```
X[ rowSums(X=="a", na.rm-TRUE) > 0 , ]
```

For the second:

```
colSums( X == "a")
```